# Verifying cart items in Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, cart, checkout

I would like to check whether there are digital and physical products at the same time in the cart and block checkout.

I have tried to do it in main-cart-items liquid, but since it's checked only at page load, it gives the same error message if some products are already deleted from the cart. I have tried something like this:

```
{% assign physical_products = 0 %}
{% assign digital_products = 0 %}
{% for item in cart.items %}
{% if item.requires_shipping %}
{% assign physical_products = physical_products  | plus : 1 %}
{% else %}
{% assign digital_products = digital_products | plus : 1 %}
{% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
{% if digital_products > 0 and physical_products > 0 %}
<p>Physical and digital products can be purchased in the same order!</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, it works, but the error is not gone if the products are deleted from the cart, only after refreshing the page.

Can I make this method work somehow?

So, I thought I add the check to cart.js and check when clicking on the checkout button, but I can't figure out how to iterate the cart items in cart.js.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asynchronous javascript to delete the items in the cart, using liquid would be more complicated since you'll have to hack something for it to load asynchronously to your page.

The best idea would be to use cart.js to check what items the user has in their cart

```js
var cartContents = fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { return data });
```

This command will return the following data:

```json
{
  "token": "1d19a32178501c44ef2223d73c54d16d",
  "note": "Hello!",
  "attributes": {
    "Gift wrap": "Yes"
  },
  "total_price": 9100,
  "total_weight": 0,
  "item_count": 3,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 794864229,
      "properties": {},
      "quantity": 1,
      "variant_id": 794864229,
      "key": "794864229:03af7a8cb59a4c3c45595c76fa8cb53c",
      "title": "Red Rain Coat - Small",
      "price": 12900,
      "line_price": 12900,
      "final_price": 12900,
      "final_line_price": 12900,
      "sku": null,
      "grams": 0,
      "vendor": "Shopify",
      "taxable": true,
      "product_id": 388319916,
      "product_has_only_default_variant": false,
      "gift_card": false,
      "url": "/products/red-rain-coat?variant=794864229",
      "featured_image": {
        "url": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0040/7092/products/red-rain-coat.jpeg?v=1402604893",
        "aspect_ratio": 1,
        "alt": "Red rain coat with a hood"
      },
      "image": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0040/7092/products/red-rain-coat.jpeg?v=1402604893",
      "handle": "red-rain-coat",
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "product_title": "Red Rain Coat",
      "product_description": "A bright red rain coat for rainy days!",
      "product_type": "Coat",
      "variant_title": "Red",
      "variant_options": [
        "Red"
      ],
      "options_with_values": [
        {
          "name": "Color",
          "value": "Red"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 794864101,
      "properties": {},
      "quantity": 2,
      "variant_id": 794864101,
      "key": "794864101:816a55d9a53cd82281f8fdcfe967db14",
      "title": "Gray Fedora",
      "price": 2650,
      "line_price": 0,
      "final_price": 2650,
      "final_line_price": 5300,
      "sku": null,
      "grams": 0,
      "vendor": "Shopify",
      "taxable": true,
      "product_id": 388319892,
      "product_has_only_default_variant": false,
      "gift_card": false,
      "url": "/products/gray-fedora?variant=794864101",
      "featured_image": {
        "url": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0040/7092/products/gray-fedora.jpeg?v=1402604885",
        "aspect_ratio": 1,
        "alt": "Gray fedora made of straw"
      },
      "image": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0040/7092/products/gray-fedora.jpeg?v=1402604885",
      "handle": "gray-fedora",
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "product_title": "Gray Fedora",
      "product_description": "A gray hat for looking cool!",
      "product_type": "Hats",
      "variant_title": "Gray",
      "variant_options": [
        "Gray"
      ],
      "options_with_values": [
        {
          "name": "Color",
          "value": "Gray"
        }
      ],
      "line_level_discount_allocations": [
        {
          "amount": 500,
          "discount_application": {
            "type": "script",
            "key": "a8a3d7aa-7d00-4827-a2e1-b03c32160bf2",
            "title": "5 Dollar Off",
            "description": null,
            "value": "5.00",
            "created_at": "2019-04-10T20:49:10.023Z",
            "value_type": "fixed_amount",
            "allocation_method": "one",
            "target_selection": "explicit",
            "target_type": "line_item",
            "total_allocated_amount": 500
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requires_shipping": true,
  "currency": "CAD",
  "items_subtotal_price": 18200,
  "cart_level_discount_applications": [
    {
      "type": "automatic",
      "key": "059b5e54-3c5d-4e7e-b377-8e09d8376269",
      "title": "50% Summer Deal",
      "description": null,
      "value": "50.0",
      "created_at": "2019-04-10T20:49:00.148Z",
      "value_type": "percentage",
      "allocation_method": "across",
      "target_selection": "all",
      "target_type": "line_item",
      "total_allocated_amount": 9100
    }
  ]
}
```

To iterate over the contents:

```js
var cartContents = fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { 
     for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
       console.log('line item', data.items[i]);
     }
   });
```

Reference: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart#get-locale-cart-js

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I almost got it, but I still have a bit issue with async fetch. 
I'm trying something like this:
`var checkout = document.getElementById("btn__checkout");
checkout.addEventListener("click", async function(e){
  var cartContents = await fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart.js')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 

      ....
          if(physicalProductsInCart > 0 && digitalProductsInCart > 0){
            e.preventDefault();
          }
     
        });
});`